# apigility db connected service with many_to_many relations

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework, many-to-many, laminas-api-tools

I'm new to ZF and apigility.
I've tried to create DB-connected service with almost zero-configuration.
Everything works well, I've got simple CRUD api, but there's one thing that I did not find solution for.
I have two tables: venues and categories
and a pivot table categories_venues to manage many_to_many relationship.
When I'm trying to create the services from tables everything works fine excepting the pivot tables. As I understood somehow because of the underscore in the name of pivot table.
So I have two questions.

1. How can I solve this so apigility could discover the table and import it?
2. How can I setup custom routes to get the listing using the following pattern /category/venue ? Is there any magic like in Rails? Can I get all the venues in the particular category? And vice versa?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please check here: [issue:many2many relations](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-doctrine/issues/21)